# ScalaMock, Unexpected call: <mock-1> when sharing mock instance between tests

Tags: scala, unit-testing, testing, scalatest, scalamock

I am using `Scala 2.10` with `ScalaMock 3.6`.

I have a quite simple test case with 4 test scenarios. I have created a `mock` object for those tests to use (imitating file system):

```
class ProcessingOperatorTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterEach with MockFactory {
...

val fakeFS = mock[FileIO]
(fakeFS.createFile _).expects(*).returns(true).anyNumberOfTimes()
(fakeFS.exist _).expects(where { (p: String) => p.contains(existing) }).returns(true).anyNumberOfTimes()
(fakeFS.exist _).expects(where { (p: String) => p.contains(notExisting) }).returns(false).anyNumberOfTimes()

behavior of "Something"
it should "test 1" in {
   ...
}

it should "test 2" in {
   ...
}

it should "test 3" in {
   ...
}

it should "test 4" in {
   ...
}
```

Now:

- 1st test does not use any of mocked methods (but needs the mock object)
- 2nd test uses only `existing` mock method
- 3rd test uses both `existing` and `not existing` mock methods
- 4th test uses all methods, (also `createFile`)

Now, for some reason, when running all those tests together, 4th test fails giving me the following error. If running separately, it will pass.

```
Unexpected call: <mock-1> FileIO.exist(notExisting)

Expected:
inAnyOrder {

}

Actual:
  <mock-1> FileIO.exist(notExisting)
ScalaTestFailureLocation: scala.Option at (Option.scala:120)
org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: Unexpected call: <mock-1> FileIO.exist(notExisting)

...
```

The other walkaround is to copy-paste the `mock` declaration and its behaviour inside 4th `it should { ... }` test scenario. Tests work then (separately, and all together).

Why is global `mock` instance failing? 
I can try to prepare a similar test scenario as separate `sbt` project if needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mix in `org.scalatest.OneInstancePerTest` as described [here](http://scalamock.org/user-guide/sharing-scalatest/):

```
class ProcessingOperatorTest extends FlatSpec
                             with Matchers
                             with BeforeAndAfterEach
                             with MockFactory
                             with OneInstancePerTest {
  ...
}
```